# How to change JDBC-URL - setting clientWorkstationName

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have a Spring Boot MultiTenant Application, using Spring Data JPA.

With extending AbstractRoutingDataSource I can change the jdbc-URL depending on tenant.

Due to company regulations, I have to provide the clientWorkstationName with each JPA-Connection.

With JDBC this is simple, adding the name as parameter to the JDBC-URL. Is there a way to do this with Spring Data?

Thx